# Combine if/else into one statement? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

```
function changeButton () {
    if (event.currentTarget.className == 'btnRed') {
        event.currentTarget.className = 'btnGreen';
    } else {
        event.currentTarget.className = 'btnRed';
    }
}
```

Let's say I have the above code. I have seen similar codes written that would combine these two, but I don't really remember how it did it. It was something like `className = (btnGreen | btnRed)`.
I am very sorry for the vagueness of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator `(condition) ? (true) : (false)`

```
event.currentTarget.className = event.currentTarget.className == 'btnRed' ? 'btnGreen' : 'btnRed';
```

I would go a little bit further, extract the strings into variables to remove the ability to mistype them across the solution. And refactor `event.currentTarget` into a variable.

```
var RED_BUTTON_CLASS = 'btnRed', 
    GREEN_BUTTON_CLASS = 'btnGreen';

var currentTarget = event.currentTarget;

currentTarget.className = currentTarget.className == RED_BUTTON_CLASS ? GREEN_BUTTON_CLASS : RED_BUTTON_CLASS;
```

This I feel will just make it easier in the long run, **completely optional**

***Edit***

So adding extra information from what Jan said.

```
var RED_BUTTON_CLASS = 'btnRed', 
    GREEN_BUTTON_CLASS = 'btnGreen';
```

These probably describe a state, so you could better name them:

```
var ERROR_BUTTON_CLASS = 'btnRed', 
    OK_BUTTON_CLASS = 'btnGreen';
```

Comment: And while you're at it, remove the references to "red" and "green" and instead describe their actions/states. "red" or "green" is likely to change in a redesign, "pressed", "hover" or "disabled" f.e are not.

Comment: It's ECMAScript name is the [*Conditional Operator ( ? : )*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-conditional-operator), which is a ternary operator. ;-)